# Template file renders on local install, not on web

Tags: custom-taxonomy, templates, custom-post-type-archives

I've been building a website that involves a child theme of Twenty Twelve and a custom post type with associated custom taxonomy, "area". I've built a template file (cribbed from code found elsewhere) to render an taxonomy archive  of this post type, `taxonomy-area.php`.

I've been experimenting on my desktop MAMP install, and when I get things the way I like them, upload them to my web hosting service (Dreamhost, fwiw), or reproducing the configuration there. Not the most efficient way to do business, I admit, but I haven't had any success with any of the staging/production plugins.

Anyhow, this taxonomy-area.php file works as expected on my desktop. But the "meat" of the template fails to render—that is, the PHP between `<? get_header(); ?>` and `<?php get_sidebar(); ?>`

That code is as follows:

```
    <section id="primary" class="site-content">
    <div id="content" role="main">
 <?php $term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) ); ?>
  <?php 
   $posts = query_posts($query_string . '&orderby=title&order=asc&posts_per_page=-1');
  if (have_posts()) : ?>
<header class="archive-header">
    <h1 class="archive-title">Area Listing: <?php echo $term->name; ?></h1>
 </header>
  <dl>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
      <?php $url = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'honyaku_url', true); ?>
      <?php $desc = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'honyaku_description', true); ?>
        <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
        <header></header>
        <div class="entry-content">
        <dt>
          <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" rel="bookmark">
            <?php the_title(); ?>
          </a>
        </dt>
        <dd><?php echo $desc; ?></dd>
        <div><!-- class="entry-content" -->
        </article>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </dl>
  <?php endif; ?>

    </div><!-- #content -->
</section><!-- #primary -->
```

The output HTML is as follows:

```
<section id="primary" class="site-content">
    <div id="content" role="main">



    </div><!-- #content -->
</section><!-- #primary -->
```

Comment: Turn on debugging, please and post what you see.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. Appears to be a [PEBCAK](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/PEBCAK) situation